# Heroku frontend timeouts when uploading file through API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I have a RESTful Rails API that's hosted on Heroku. I also have a Rails front-end on Heroku that consumes my API. I'm having an issue with the front-end timing out when uploading a file. I send the upload request to my front-end (done with `jquery-fileupload-rails`), and that in turn sends a request to my API. However, with even a 1MB file, it seems that the front-end times out and gives up on waiting to hear back from the API. The file upload works fine. If I refresh the page, the image is there. However, I'd much rather update my page with the image dynamically. Smaller files seem to work, likely because the front-end hears back from the API soon enough.

I know that Heroku has a 500ms time limit on requests, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that, so I was hoping I could get some advice on this issue. Is this just not going to work on Heroku? Should I approach ajax file uploads to an API differently? Or am I going to have to just refresh the page if it times out (not sure how I would do that either)? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your files to a different service, like Amazon's S3. Uploading directly to Heroku is never a good idea.

Comment: I am using S3 for storage. My API on Heroku uploads to it using Paperclip. I know there's an option to directly go to S3, but I need Imagemagick to do some processing on them first so I don't see it as an option.

Comment: It gets more complicated, but you upload to S3, and asynchronously you do the processing by calling reprocess! on the image object.